# DatePicker upper part is blank

Tags: android, datepicker, material-design

I am using Android's native DatePicker in the following way and it is working fine but the view is somehow coming to be not proper.

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    DatePickerDialog dialog;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        dialog= new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(new Date().getTime());
        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return dialog;
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Doing some stuff here
    }
}
```

And, calling it like this :

```
DialogFragment datePickerFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
datePickerFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "startDate");
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem by removing this line from **v21/styles.xml** file.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!--<item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>-->
</style>
```

Because of this line all custom views(fragments, dialogs, etc.) were bydefault picking a white background.